# MVC Uri Parameter is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When attempting to pass a parameter to a simple controller I receive the parameter as always being null.

**Controller**

```
public class GetOrgController : Controller
{
    private DirectoryEntities de;

    public getOrgController()
    {
        de = new DirectoryEntities();
    }
    // GET: getOrg
    public ActionResult Index(string district)
    {
        getorg_Result org = de.getorg(district).FirstOrDefault();
        return View(org);
    }
}
```

When I try to navigate to that url with a parameter `localhost:660366/GetOrg/Index/D123` the district variable is always `null`.

I thought maybe it had to do something with the default `RouteConfig`. When I put a new value ahead of the default route config it worked! However now, whenever I try to launch the application it goes to the `GetOrgController` first. What happens when I want a new controller with different parameters? I have to do this every time? Here is my new RouteConfig with the new entry.

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "GetOrg",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{district}",
    defaults: new { controller = "GetOrg", action = "Index", district = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

I actually started doing Rest initially in Web Api 2, but the view-model attracted me to MVC. It is a lot easier specifiying above the method the routes/parameters I wanted like below. Is this possible in MVC?

> WebApi2

```
[Route("Index/{district}")]
public ActionResult Index(string district)
{
    getorg_Result orgs = de.getorg(district).FirstOrDefault();
    return View(orgs);
}
```

The above method seems so much cleaner than having to rely on the order of controllers being correct in the `RouteConfig`

Comment: why not just name district Id?

Comment: `...I wanted like below. Is this possible in MVC?` <= It seems that is possible. See [MVC 5 Routing Attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38103475/1260204).

Comment: Like @ErikPhilips answered below, your 2 routes conflict with each other. They are completely identical, the first one to get hit will be the first one in the defined list.

Comment: Don't be fooled that you can simply switch to the `RouteAttribute` and now order magically doesn't matter, because it still does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two routes literally make no sense.  The first one says, for *ANY* controller with *ANY* method default to `GetOrgController`.  That isn't what you want because now `id` won't work for all the other controllers and the second `MapRoute` is close to a duplicate.

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "GetOrg",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{district}",
        defaults: new { controller = "GetOrg", action = "Index", district = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

What you really should be doing is saying for any call starting with GetOrg then call `GetOrgController` for any method....

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "GetOrg",
        url: "GetOrg/{action}/{district}",
        defaults: new { controller = "GetOrg", action = "Index", district = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Answer (score -1):

thats because both routs are generic thats why it hits the first route by default so you can remove `UrlParameter.Optional` so that the route should be a little specific

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "GetOrg",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{district}",
        defaults: new { controller = "GetOrg", action = "Index"}
    );
```

but still you can use the default route for that purpose no need of additional route unless you want to use a custom url like `random/234`