# Angular Call to MVC Controller Function

Tags: javascript, c#, angular

I'm fairly new to Angular and I am having some trouble finding the answer to my problem. I'm using Angular 11 with ASP.NET MVC in visual studio, and I am trying to invoke a MVC controller once a button is clicked in my app.component.html. I have looked all over the place, but all the answers are either for AngularJS or ASP.NET Core which doesn't really help me at all. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

app.component.html

```
<div style="padding-left: 140px">
      <button (click)="onImportClick()" class="dv-button" style="width: 
100px; padding: 4px 6px">
        Import
      </button>
    </div>
```

app.component.ts

```
onImportClick() {
this.importErrors = [];


this.appService.callImport(4).subscribe()

    this.clearFile();
    //window.location.reload();
  

 }
}
```

app.service.ts

```
export class AppService {

private baseUrl = "http://localhost:4200/";
private importUrl = this.baseUrl + 'Import/GetTest';
private test = ["test"];
myBooks: string[];


constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

callImport(id: any) {

let body = JSON.stringify(id);
return this.http.get('Import/GetTest').pipe(map(
data => {
this.myBooks = [body];

    }
   )
  );
}
```

ImportController.cs

```
namespace AI.Controllers.AI_API
{  
 public class ImportController: IController
 {
      
      public void Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
      {
           throw new NotImplementedException();
      }

      [Route("/Import/GetTest")]
      public int GetTest(int id)
      {
           var result = id;
           return result;
      }
 }
}
```

RouteConfig.cs

```
public class RouteConfig
 {
      public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
      {
           routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

           routes.MapRoute(
               name: "Default",
               url: "{controller}/{action}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"}
           );

          
      }
 }
```

Comment: Don't *only* describe what you are doing, edit the post and add the relevant code.

Comment: @R.Richards sorry about that. I added the code.

Comment: Does your angular app fire off the request? Can you trap the call with the debugger in your controller action?

Comment: I'm not sure the request is ever reaching the controller action because when I click on the button that has the onClick() function, the developer tools on my browser give me a 500 error saying "The method or operation is not implemented." It also says "Http failure response for https://localhost:44307/Import/GetTest: 500 OK"

Comment: @Jasen sorry forgot to tag you above

Comment: If you visit `https://localhost:44307/Import/GetTest` with your browser or with Postman what do you get? Get that working first.

Comment: I get:

public void Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
Line 18:           {
Line 19:                throw new NotImplementedException();
Line 20:           }

[NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.] @Jasen

Comment: So it routes and you are forcing a NotImplementedException. Just drop that Execute method.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are implementing `IController`? Just extend `Controller`.

Comment: Okay I removed the execute method and stopped implementing IController. Now when I go to https://localhost:44307/Import/GetTest, it says "HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

Comment: I used IController because the developer tools was saying "The controller for path /Import/GetTest was not found or does not implement IController" @Jasen

Comment: See here to get MVC Attribute Routing configured https://stackoverflow.com/a/38103475/2030565

Comment: Thank you so much, you're a life saver! It is starting to work now. @Jasen